# Retain UIViewController or not in navigation stack

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a scenario that I'm not sure whether to retain a view controller or not. Say I had `ViewControllerOne`. When a button was pressed, `ViewControllerOne` would push `ViewControllerTwo` in the navigation stack. `ViewControllerTwo` needs a reference to `ViewControllerOne` because it needs to access an ivar in that view controller. The question is, would I retain `ViewControllerOne` in `ViewControllerTwo` (`@property (retain) ViewControllerOne *vc`) or not? The navigation controller already retains the `ViewControllerOne` so I'm not really sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably set viewControllerOne up as a delegate of viewControllerTwo.  In general, a delegate is not retained.

As you have described it, viewControllerTwo does not need to know anything about viewControllerOne in particular, it just needs to know how to access a piece of data and inform a higher level object of changes to that data.  That is a common role for a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: Why does `ViewControllerTwo` need to access an ivar from `ViewControllerOne` ?

The better approach would be to pass the value of the ivar in `ViewControllerOne` to `ViewControllerTwo` before pushing `ViewControllerTwo` to the stack.

Comment: Ok, so would I assign a reference to the ivar in ViewControllerTwo, or would I retain it? I want any changes made to the ivar in ViewControllerTwo to be reflected in ViewControllerOne

Answer (score 0):

Ranpraygo is correct.

The best solution is to add a property to ViewControllerTwo and pass the iVar from ViewControllerOne to it before pushing it to the navigation stack.

By convention the property added to ViewControllerTwo should be retained if it is an object although you could get away with an assigned property in this example because the ViewControllerTwo will be released before ViewControllerOne is and I assume ViewControllerOne has retained the iVar

In objectiveC all variables that are objects are passed by reference primitives and structs are passed by value as they would be in C